# How can I get the script source code from jQuery

Tags: jquery

Take a look to the following small code block

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/jquery-min.js"></script>
<script id="the-script" type="text/javascript" src="http://otherdomain.com/js/some-script.js"></script>
<script>
   /*
     console.log(jQuery("#the-script").some-property);
   */
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

With `jQuery("#the-script").some-property` I am asking for some property that allow me get the source code of the script as a text (string). Is there any property for that purpose?

Comment: What is your intended purpose
?

Comment: that falls outside the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), so no.

Comment: maybe send to your server an ajax request which will call a server script which will proxified the content of the javascript file then returns the content

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Read: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: I am trying to parse every javascript code to find some string. I need do so from client side, not server side.

Comment: @gsc-delmo And why do you need to parse JS code?

Answer (score 0):

You can send `ajax` request for the content of that file and do whatever with it.
I made a fiddle where I loaded jQuery source code into span element to show you how this can work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7X6Z/

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin will denied access if not allowed by external server. Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7X6Z/1/